# IOS Device Orientation Stuck at Portrait mode, no Landscape

Tags: ios, xcode, ios-simulator, orientation, portrait

I'm using Xcode 4.3.2 and an iPad simulator 5.1

I really need some help with this, my app is stuck at portrait mode.

When I rotate the simulator
I've tried looking under the project settings and have these checked:
Portrait, Upside Down, Landscape Left and Landscape Right.

I also these methods in the view controllers:

```
- (BOOL)shouldAutorotateToInterfaceOrientation:(UIInterfaceOrientation)interfaceOrientation
{
    return YES;
}
```

can anyone please help?

Comment: When you port to IOS 6 you will need additional code: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12565693/xcode-4-5-ios-6-0-simulator-orientation-not-working/12568678#12568678

Answer (score 3):

Check your supporting orientations in the project's settings or on `*.plist` file. Also, if you are using `UITabBarController` or smth else, all of your controllers have to support all orientations!

Comment: I already made sure in the project settings and the plist that all orientations are enabled. This is a simple Single View Application "Hello World" app. What do you mean by that? Sorry I'm a beginner trying to learn Xcode..

Comment: Press '+' button at the left of the orientation name and chose the one of the list. And again until you have all 4 orientations. Doesn't matter, what king of app it is.

Comment: OK. Again, you have only `AppDelegate` and `ViewController` classes, no more? In the project's settings all orientations are enabled and in `ViewController` class you have `shouldAutorotateToInterfaceOrientation:` method, that returns `YES`? If all of it is true, I don't know, what may cause a problem. Can you check your app on device?

Comment: Thank you for helping me. I looked at the settings and the method and they exists. Yes, I only have AppDelegate.h, AppDelegate.m, ViewController.h and ViewController.m. On the MainStoryboard.storyboard there are 2 view controllers and an Navigation Controller and a button. I dont have a developers account yet, so I can't test it. The app is still only to support portrait orientation. Heres the project:http://www.mediafire.com/download.php?898z24aauv2e064 Maybe I'm missing something obvious here?

Comment: Honestly, I've never used storyboard :) So wait, I'll try to figure it out.

Comment: Thank you for your effort I appreaciate it :-)

Hope it doesn't tak to loong, hehe.

Comment: Well, I really don't know what's wrong. I'd recommend you to create the new project without storyboard. So, if you'll have any questions, I would try to help :)

Comment: Here's what's wrong with your sample project. If you go to the View controller, and go to the identity inspector, the class name is set to LKViewController. I don't know what that is but if you want it to point to your customer view controller `ViewController`, you need to change the name appropriately: ViewController in the Class field. I did that and since you properly overrode the `- (BOOL)shouldAutorotateToInterfaceOrientation:(UIInterfaceOrientation)interfaceOrientation` it all works.

Answer (score 1):

use cmd+shift+f and type - (BOOL)shouldAutorotateToInterfaceOrientation:(UIInterfaceOrientation)interfaceOrientation

make sure all of them return YES if you want all orientations supported and NO For unsupported orientations

Comment: Thanks, the only file that had that was ViewController.m, and it was already set to return YES. Still having this problem.. heres the project: http://mediafire.com/download.php?898z24aauv2e064 (a simple "hello world" view controller)

Answer (score 1):

Make sure you only have one controller showing. I've seen this problem when I have multiple views with different controllers showing at the same time.

Comment: It's a single view controller app?

Comment: Does the status bar rotate? In a single view app, you can have multiple subviews. if they have their own controllers, you will have this problem. The status bar rotates but not the root controller.

Comment: The iOS bar is always the opposite to the home button on the simulator. I think this is the problem? but I don't know where to start fixing it, can you please help? btw, heres the screenshot of the storyboard: http://imgur.com/Wuhfn

Comment: Anybody with a solution? I'm still having trouble autorotating this hello world app.. Please?

Answer (score 1):

Yeah I had the same problem and the other answers here didn't fix my situation.  I found I had to **check the "Resize View from NIB" box in all the relevant views**.

See screenshot below (although shows a slightly older version of XCode).

[image]