# Xcode 4.5 iOS 6.0 simulator orientation not working

Tags: ios-simulator, orientation, xcode4.5

I have updated my Xcode to 4.5 , I have implemented the orientation methods as below

```
  -(BOOL)shouldAutorotate{

    return YES;

  }

-(NSUInteger)supportedInterfaceOrientations{

    return UIInterfaceOrientationMaskAll;
}
```

I am setting the frame sizes of buttons ,labels,images in willRotateToInterfaceOrientation method

```
-(void)willRotateToInterfaceOrientation:(UIInterfaceOrientation)toInterfaceOrientation duration:(NSTimeInterval)duration{


  if ([[UIDevice currentDevice] orientation] == UIDeviceOrientationPortrait )||
        ([[UIDevice currentDevice] orientation] == UIDeviceOrientationPortraitUpsideDown ))
  {

    // set frame sizes for portait

   }

  else if(( [[UIDevice currentDevice] orientation] == UIDeviceOrientationLandscapeLeft )||
            ([[UIDevice currentDevice] orientation] == UIDeviceOrientationLandscapeRight ))

  {

    // set frame sizes for landscape

   }

}
```

but sometimes this method is not getting called when rotating the simulator and
sometimes the simulator is not detecting orientation when navigating from another viewController . I have checked info.plist file - it is fine.

Comment: -(BOOL)shouldAutorotateToInterfaceOrientation:
(UIInterfaceOrientation)interfaceOrientation
not -(BOOL)shouldAutorotate   also did you set the view controller for the windows?

Comment: check this out: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12772749/support-different-orientation-for-only-one-view-ios-6

Answer (score 4):

Apple does not call the shouldAutorotatetoInterfaceOrientation call in IOS 6.0 unless you tell the main window which view controller to send it to.

I got rotation to work in my app by setting the window.rootViewController to the top level view controller of my app in

```
-(BOOL)application:(UIApplication *)application didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:(NSDictionary *)launchOptions
{
   ...
   window.rootViewController = topLevelViewController;
   ...
}
```

The iPhone version of my app only supports the two portrait orientations, so my top iPhone view controller required a new method:

```
- (NSUInteger)supportedInterfaceOrientations 
{
  return  UIInterfaceOrientationMaskPortrait |  
          UIInterfaceOrientationMaskPortraitUpsideDown;
}
```

here is a discussion on [Buzz Touch](http://www.buzztouch.com/forum/thread.php?tid=41ED2FC151397D4AD4A5A60&currentPage=1).

Comment: Thanks god, i searched for exactly this information for about one hour.....there are many informations which aren't working anymore. Shame on apple that they are not downwards compatible!

Comment: Excellent answer.  As Felix mentions, there's a LOT of discussion about this issue, but many confusing answers.  This first piece of code was the piece of the puzzle that allowed me to get this working with iOS 5 and iOS 6

Answer (score 0):

Apple has deprecated shouldautorate method from ios6 use these methods instead

```
- (BOOL)shouldAutorotate NS_AVAILABLE_IOS(6_0);
- (NSUInteger)supportedInterfaceOrientations NS_AVAILABLE_IOS(6_0);
// Returns interface orientation masks.
- (UIInterfaceOrientation)preferredInterfaceOrientationForPresentation NS_AVAILABLE_IOS(6_0);
```