# From Portrait mode to Landscape mode in iOS5, iOS6

Tags: ios6, xcode4.5, autorotate, landscape-portrait

I want to turn only one of my views within my app to landscape right. 
All my other views are in portrait mode. Previous view is in portrait mode. I pushed landscape view to portrait view. How can I do it correctly? 
[image: This portrait(rootviewcontroller)]

[image: This landscape]

in my landscape view controller:

```
//Orientation
-(BOOL) shouldAutorotateToInterfaceOrientation:(UIInterfaceOrientation)toInterfaceOrientation{
    return (toInterfaceOrientation == UIInterfaceOrientationLandscapeRight);
}
// New Autorotation support
-(BOOL)shouldAutorotate {
    return YES;
}

-(NSUInteger)supportedInterfaceOrientations{
    return UIInterfaceOrientationMaskLandscapeRight;
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've solved. Thanks Sang. I used [this example:](https://github.com/sunilpandey/DifferentOrientation)

Also see [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12772749/support-different-orientation-for-only-one-view-ios-6)

Or [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12520030/how-to-force-a-uiviewcontroller-to-portait-orientation-in-ios-6)

Answer (score 0):

You can use this in you view controller

```
- (BOOL)shouldAutorotateToInterfaceOrientation:(UIInterfaceOrientation)interfaceOrientation
{
    return (interfaceOrientation == UIInterfaceOrientationLandscapeRight);
}
```

this will make sure the orientation is landscape right.

Comment: this method is deprecated in ios6

Answer (score 0):

For changing the orientation in a device you can do sum thng like this..

```
-(void)viewDidLoad
{
    orientation = [[UIDevice currentDevice] orientation];
    if(intOrientation == UIInterfaceOrientationLandscapeRight)
                orientation = UIDeviceOrientationLandscapeRight;

}
```

Hope it helps you