# Autorotation not working ios6.1

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios6, autorotate

Autorotation is not working in ios6.1. But following code is working in other app.

code:

```
@implementation UINavigationController (RotationIn_IOS6)

-(BOOL)shouldAutorotate
{
    return [[self.viewControllers lastObject] shouldAutorotate];
}

-(NSUInteger)supportedInterfaceOrientations
{
    return [[self.viewControllers lastObject] supportedInterfaceOrientations];
}

- (UIInterfaceOrientation)preferredInterfaceOrientationForPresentation
{
    return [[self.viewControllers lastObject]  preferredInterfaceOrientationForPresentation];
}

@end


- (BOOL)shouldAutorotate
{
    //returns true if want to allow orientation change
    return TRUE;


}
- (NSUInteger)supportedInterfaceOrientations
{
    //decide number of origination tob supported by Viewcontroller.
    return UIInterfaceOrientationMaskAll;


}

- (UIInterfaceOrientation)preferredInterfaceOrientationForPresentation
{
    //from here you Should try to Preferred orientation for ViewController

    return UIInterfaceOrientationLandscapeLeft | UIInterfaceOrientationLandscapeRight | UIInterfaceOrientationPortrait;
}

- (void)willAnimateRotationToInterfaceOrientation:(UIInterfaceOrientation)  interfaceOrientation duration:(NSTimeInterval)duration
{

}
```

Comment: Check your project settings for allowed orientations - all supported must be selected , check my answer here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15835084/restricting-autorotation-on-certain-views/15835584#15835584

Comment: Yes I selected all orientation. But not working

Comment: Did you implement these method in the controllers that should actually rotate?

Comment: yes i implemented in viewcontroller

Comment: it seems that you made a typo somewhere, check your code carefully one more time.

Comment: Did you set your window's rootViewController ? Or add subview?

Comment: HomeVC *home_obj=[[HomeVC alloc]init];
 UINavigationController *nav1=[[UINavigationController alloc]initWithRootViewController:home_obj];
 [window addSubview:nav1.view];
    
    //window.rootViewController=nav1;
 
    [self.window makeKeyAndVisible];

Comment: Yes, I also experienced with same problem. I solved by setting `window.rootViewCotroller = nav1 ;` You can try this. I hope this will be work..

Comment: when i use window.rootViewCotroller = nav1. My viewcontroller is transparent view display. Nothing shows inside view

Answer (score 1):

ios6 uses mainly the plist options for autorotation. Try to setup the supported orientations fields.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried to modify the plist?

Answer (score 0):

Please check your project targets summery is like below

[image]

Comment: -(BOOL)shouldAutorotateToInterfaceOrientation:(UIInterfaceOrientation)toInterfaceOrientation
{

    return YES;
    
}

Comment: - (BOOL)shouldAutorotate {
    
    
    return YES;
}

Comment: first remove all methods for rotation in coding then apply this three methods