# Change Orientation for Youtube Videos ONLY

Tags: ios, iphone, objective-c, video, youtube

I currently have my iPhone application orientation set to Portrait only and was wondering if it were possible to change the orientation of a Youtube video, since it comes up in its own modal view controller?

I have a UIWebView that has a youtube video in there and when clicking it, it brings up the youtube/apple media player in a modal view controller. Is it possible to only change the orientation of this video player, to three orientations, and then reset it back to portrait once it is done?

I noticed in another post that these two help see if the movie player is active and inactive but I have not figured out how to change the orientation and then reset it. Any guidance and help is appreciated in advance. Thanks!

Code that is used to check for Movie Player start/finish

```
[[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] addObserver:self selector:@selector(youTubeStarted:) name:@"UIMoviePlayerControllerDidEnterFullscreenNotification" object:nil];
[[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] addObserver:self selector:@selector(youTubeFinished:) name:@"UIMoviePlayerControllerWillExitFullscreenNotification" object:nil];
```

Does anyone know how to control or grab the UIMoviePlayerController? Maybe there is someway to intercept it and control its orientation.

Comment: Take a look on it: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12772749/support-different-orientation-for-only-one-view-ios-6

Comment: @RobertoFerraz: Just attempted it, and it's not working.